# Laravel 7 automatic scoping in resource route

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

is there a way to use the new automatic scoping in resource routes? Everything I tried didn't work:

```
Route::apiResource('instances/{instance:id}/projects', 'ProjectController', [
    'except' => ['destroy']
]);
```

The following manual solution is working but would be a mess in the routes file.

```
Route::get('instances/{instance:id}/project/{project:id}',function(Instance $instance, Project $project){
    return response()->json($project);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and as far as I can tell, the custom route key needs to be specified on the *nested* resource to trigger automatic scoping. The easiest way to do it without specifying each route separately is probably using `parameters()`:

```
Route::apiResource('instances.projects', 'ProjectController')->parameters([
    'projects' => 'project:id'
]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I already tried it with project but not projects.

Answer (score 0):

it is probably help you

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'instances/{instance:id}'], function () {
    Route::apiResource('project', 'ProjectController', [
        'except' => ['destroy']
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it could be an issue your models are in some other directory. you have to resolve the models first to be injected.

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('instance', App\Instance::class);
    Route::model('project', App\Project::class);
}
```

You have to explicitly bind the models to keys.

```
Route::get('instances/{instance:id}/project/{project:id}',function(Instance $instance, Project $project){
    return response()->json($project);
});
```